# Using old command line in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I know that the command line has been replaced by the Python Window, but is there any way to use command line within ArcMap 10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

I have asked our local ESRI support recently, their statement being that the old command line is dropped completely. Bothers me as well. You can still execute GP tools from the Python window.